# How to check whether the specific value exists in a column?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to check if the value exists in a column. For example I want to check that column `artId` contains some numeric value. I'm using following code:

```
getStar = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "artId" },
                        "artId = " + entryId, null, null,
                        null, null);
        getStar.moveToFirst();
        String star = getStar.toString();
        Log.w("ID COUNT", star);
        if(getStar != null) {
            // do something
        }
```

Where `entryId` is some number.

But I always get something like this:

`W/ID COUNT(11303): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41aa4c80`.

Also I tried to use:

```
getStar = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM "
+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE artId = '" + entryId + "'", null);
```

But I got the same result.

So I hope for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Cursor` is valid (non-`null`), yes, because it has no errors. Check if it has any data, instead.

```
getStar = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE artId = '" + entryId + "'", null);
getStar.moveToFirst();
if (getStar.getInt(0)) { // This will get the integer value of the COUNT(*)
    // It has data
}
```

I'm a bit unsure of the results of the above; instead, you could query the number of results:

```
getStar = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE artId = '" + entryId + "'", null);
if (getStar.getCount() > 0) { // This will get the number of rows
    // It has data
}
```

Comment: The first solution works too. At least when there are no values exist and when exists only 1 value.

Answer (score 1):

moveTofirst() method try to move the cursor into the first position (0 based) and it returns true if that can be done. Otherwise it returns false. So you could do like that:

```
if (getStar.moveToFirst) {
// your code
} else {}
```

if there is an value if statement will be executed otherwise it won't

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the cursor `String` representation, not the value of the column `artId`.
To get the value of the column `artId` from your cursor you have to something like this :

```
int count = -1;
// if the cursor is not empty
if(getStar.moveTofirst())
    count = getStar.getInt(getStar.getColumnIndex("artId");

if(count != -1)
    // do something
```